# Determine table existence

Tags: mysql

I got this piece of code from Mysql 4th edition to check table existence

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE FALSE;
```

I cant quite under stand the `where` clause.
If im not mistaken there is no boolean type in mysql, so basically it been cast to

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 0;
```

And should it be a column on a `where` clause?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = false;
```

Any explaination greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it doesn't have to have column as operand :)

When you open mysql [select manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) than [expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/expressions.html) you would find there `simple_expr` what should mean conditions like `WHERE 1` (about [booleans](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/boolean-literals.html)) but I understand it can be confusing (and it's rare to use conditions without columns).

When you do `SELECT * FROM table WHERE FALSE;` it's basically this:

```
if there's table `table`
    return 0 rows (minimal database overhead) and valid resource
else
    return false
```

Just take a look on return values from [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

Answer (score 0):

**Checking on a Table's Existence**

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $table";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result)
{
// table does not exist
}
```

**To answer your question:**

The `where` clause is used to retrieve the value of a column in the given table. For example, if your table consists of two columns (user_id, user_name), your query might look something like the following:

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM $table where user_id = 1";
```

Lastly, you may read more about the `where` clause [at this link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp)

Comment: Mind explaining the down vote? If this answer is lacking in any way I will gladly expand on any of the points made.

Comment: When I read your answer and downvoted it only had the first part, which didn't answer the question (it's also a really inefficient way to check if a table exists). Looking at your edit now you're still not really answering the question, which is asking about the meaning of a where clause without a column.

Comment: @Paul off topic- I'm also from Albany, NY :)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that MySQL 4.x supports ANSI.  If so, you could try the following:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = <schema-or-db-name> 
AND table_name = <table-or-view-name>
```